# spring security redirecting to login page on click of any link after successful login

Tags: spring-security, hippocms

I am trying to implement spring security-3.0.7 in an application which uses hippo as a content management system. I can able to login web application successfully after login if I click any link it redirecting to login page again. Here is `web.xml` and `spring-security.xml`. Can you please advise what might be the reason for redirecting to login page.

## web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    
            </context-param>
            <context-param>
                <param-name>hst-beans-annotated-classes</param-name>
                <param-value>
                classpath*:org/onehippo/forge/security/support/springsecurity/beans/**/*.class
            </param-value>
            </context-param>
             <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
              /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
              /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
            </param-value>
          </context-param>
        
          <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
          </filter>
        
              <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
          </filter-mapping>
        
          <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
          </listener>
        
            <filter>
                <filter-name>ClickjackFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>com.accenture.leadership.filters.ClickjackFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>mode</param-name>
                    <!--<param-value>DENY</param-value>-->
                    <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </filter>
        
            <filter>
                <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </filter>
        
            <filter>
                <filter-name>XSSUrlFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.hippoecm.hst.container.XSSUrlFilter</filter-class>
            </filter>
        
            <filter>
                <filter-name>HstFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.hippoecm.hst.container.HstFilter</filter-class>
                        <init-param>
                    <param-name>clientComponentManagerClass</param-name>
                    <param-value>org.hippoecm.hst.component.support.ClientComponentManager</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>clientComponentManagerConfigurations</param-name>
                    <param-value>/META-INF/client-assembly/*.xml</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </filter>
        
            <filter>
                <filter-name>etag</filter-name>
                <filter-class>com.cj.etag.ETagFilter</filter-class>
            </filter>
        
            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>ClickjackFilter</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>
        
            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>etag</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>
        
            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>
        
            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>XSSUrlFilter</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>
        
            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>HstFilter</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>HstSiteConfigServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.hippoecm.hst.site.container.HstSiteConfigServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>hst-config-refresh-delay</param-name>
                    <param-value>3000</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>CustomBinaryServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>com.accenture.leadership.components.CustomBinaryServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cache-max-object-size-bytes</param-name>
                    <param-value>8388608</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.hippoecm.hst.servlet.HstFreemarkerServlet</servlet-class>
                        <init-param>
                    <param-name>TemplatePath</param-name>
                    <param-value>/</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>ContentType</param-name>
                    <param-value>text/html; charset=UTF-8</param-value>
                            </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>200</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>TemplateComposerResourceServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.hippoecm.hst.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>jarPathPrefix</param-name>
                    <param-value>/META-INF/hst/pagecomposer</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.hippoecm.hst.security.servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>SecurityResourceServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.hippoecm.hst.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>jarPathPrefix</param-name>
                    <param-value>/META-INF/hst/security</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>HstResourceServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.hippoecm.hst.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>jarPathPrefix</param-name>
                    <param-value>/META-INF/web-resources</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>PingServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.hippoecm.hst.servlet.HstPingServlet</servlet-class>
            </servlet>
        
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>CustomBinaryServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/binaries/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
        
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
        
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>TemplateComposerResourceServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/hst/pagecomposer/sources/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
        
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
        
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>SecurityResourceServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/login/hst/security/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
        
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>HstResourceServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
        
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>PingServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/ping/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
        
            <security-constraint>
                <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>Login</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/login/resource</url-pattern>
                </web-resource-collection>security-constraint
                <auth-constraint>
                    <role-name>everybody</role-name>
                </auth-constraint>
            </security-constraint>
        
            <login-config>
                <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
                <realm-name>HSTSITE</realm-name>
                <form-login-config>
                    <form-login-page>/login/login</form-login-page>
                    <form-error-page>/login/error</form-error-page>
                </form-login-config>
            </login-config>
        
            <security-role>
                <description>Default role of Hippo Repository</description>
                <role-name>everybody</role-name>
            </security-role>
        
            <security-constraint>
                <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                    <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
                    <http-method>COPY</http-method>
                    <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
                    <http-method>MKCOL</http-method>
                    <http-method>PROPFIND</http-method>
                    <http-method>PUT</http-method>
                </web-resource-collection>
                <auth-constraint />
            </security-constraint>
        </web-app>
```

## Spring-security.xml

Here is `spring-security.xml` - Is there anything is missing in this `spring-security.xml` file. What will happen I dont want use `default-target-url`.

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/binaries/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_everybody" />
        
    <form-login login-page="/"
                        default-target-url="/events"
                        always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout.jsp" />
</http>
        
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="hippoAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="hippoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.onehippo.forge.security.support.springsecurity.authentication.HippoAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

Can you suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: Please post the logs for when you authenticate. Separately, post the logs of when you make a request to a page in which the authentication occurs. You should also include the HTTP request/response for both of the requests.

Comment: Hippo has its own logging mechanism so I am not able to trace the issue.

Comment: Can you try turning on logging for Spring Security? It uses commons logging. It should work unless hippo is doing something similar to slf4j over jars. Even the you should be able to enable logging. Alternatively post a link to an example and I can take a look

Comment: You should be able to enable logging for both spring security and the HST spring security module. You can do so from the log4j-dev.xml in your project. You might also want to read www.onehippo.org/labs/setting-up-spring-security-in-hippo.html and see if there is a step you've missed. I think that your intercept-url pattern /* and /** are overlapping. It seems everything on /* is not authenticated (so /events is not authenticated).

Comment: I had enabled log4j. I was getting SecurityContext is empty in the log file then I set Authentication in SecurityContextHolder. Now when click any link its showing correct url in the browser but it displays forbidden page that is 403.